# How to check object null and then property null and then assign value if they are null?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to check if a variable is null inside an object in single line

```
 let data = {                        
   friends: userData.social.friends?0: userData.social.friends,
}
```

in the above line how to check if the userData is null and social is null and then friend is null in a single line? i need to set 0 if friends is not there.

this is in my javascript node js app

Comment: _"...is null in a single line?"_ Why? O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is *falsy* sufficient or do you actually need to compare against `null`? you could use this pretty standard notation:

```
let data = {                        
    friends: userData && userData.social && userData.social.friends || 0
}
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific? does the error have anything to do with the code above?

Comment: sorry that was throwing in a different line , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you want to check for null as well as assign the value of friends to your variable, i think it will help you out

```js
let data = {                        
 friends: userData ? (userData.social ? (userData.social.friends ? userData.social.friends : 0) : 0) : 0
}
```

I hope this fits your need.